# Gem Bundler not installed - Unable to Run Jenkins Build

Tags: ruby, build, jenkins, continuous-integration, rvm

I am trying to run a build on jenkins with ruby environment:- ruby-1.9.3-p327(installed via rvm)

I'm getting the following error:-

```
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/scripts/fetch http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p327.tar.bz2
There is no checksum for 'http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p327.tar.bz2' or 'ruby-1.9.3-p327.tar.bz2', it's not possible to validate it.
If you wish to continue with unverified download add '--verify-downloads 1' after the command.
```

I just wanted to know here exactly on the Jenkins CI server can I specify "--verify-downloads 1" .

Also, even though I have installed bundler gem in this ruby environment, it somehow isn't able to detect it.

**UPDATED**

I got the above error from the file:- /var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/fetch.log , as part of the console output for the job.

Any inputs on this would really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: it looks like installation of ruby, the error seams to be misconfiguration of rvm, are you using any integration plugin or you do stuff manually?

Comment: @mpapis Thank you for your assistance, I manually do them..